# Animate TranslateTransform on GridViewItem

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a series of items in a GridView.

I want to animate the TranslateTransform of a GridViewItem so that it is outside the boundary of the GridView. When I do, it is clipped. Is this type of transform possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think so. I had to do something similar a while ago and it turns out that the template of a GriView (and ListView, ListBox, etc...) contains a `ScrollViewer` control. The thing about the `ScrollViewer` controls is that they MUST define a clipped viewport to give the user the impression of scrolling. In fact, if you were to decompile the ScrollViewer control, you can see that it hard codes the clipped bounds, so you cant even change the template or style.

Things may have changed since I looked into this, and my investigations where on WPF not XAML in Windows 8, but I dont think that it would have changed based on your description of the issue.

Here is a SO question in relation to this topic: [WPF clipping even when no clipping is desired - how to turn it off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856225/wpf-clipping-even-when-no-clipping-is-desired-how-to-turn-it-off)