# WPF: Negative margin gets clipped in ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf

I have a `TabControl` which is styled and templated in a way that the tab header and the tab content are separated by a line, but the current selected tab breaks this line (see picture 1).[image]

This works like a charm, except for two things.

**First problem:** In certain zoom states (unfortunately in default state 100% as well) there is a very thin line separating the tab header from the content (see picture 2; the height of the separation line is 2px).[image]

Where does it come from and how can I get rid of it?

Since the current selected tab might get a left, top and right border later on I can't just increase the negative margin, because the left and right border would be visible in the content.

---

**Second problem:** If I put the tab header inside a `ScrollViewer` to be able to horizontally scroll through the tabs (in case there are too many), the negative `Margin` gets clipped and the separation line is shown.
Of course the `ScrollViewer` is styled and templated in a way to not use the horizontal scrollbar below the content.

How can I use negative `Margin` inside a `ScrollViewer`?

I commented out the `ScrollViewer` in my code below. Please remove the comment indicators and please remove the `Margin` on the `TabPanel` inside the `ScrollViewer` to see the problem in action.

Here's my styles and templates and code, in case someone needs it:

```
<Style x:Key="TabControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Border x:Name="Content"
                            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="0,2,0,0"
                            Background="White">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                          ContentSource="SelectedContent"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>

                    <!--<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,0">-->
                    <TabPanel x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                              Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                              Margin="5,5,5,0"
                              IsItemsHost="True" />
                    <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                        <TextBlock x:Name="TabTitle"
                                   Margin="16,6"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" TargetName="Border" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" TargetName="Border" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,-2" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,-2,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" TargetName="Border" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" TargetName="Border" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication" 
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
    </Window.LayoutTransform>

    <TabControl Style="{StaticResource TabControlStyle}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}">
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab Two" />
        <TabItem Header="Tab III" />
    </TabControl>

</Window>
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I changed these references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first problem, you can increase your negative margins by separating the border from the content:

```
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--SeparatorLine will be rendered on bottom-->
    <Border x:Name="SeparatorLine"
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="0,2,0,0">
    </Border>

    <!--Tabs will be rendered on top of the SeparatorLine-->
    <TabPanel x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="5,5,5,0"
            IsItemsHost="True" />

    <!--Content will be rendered on top. Content.Margin should equal the SeparatorLine.BorderThickness-->
    <Border x:Name="Content"
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="0,2,0,0"
            Background="White">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                          ContentSource="SelectedContent"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Now you are free to use negative margin in `TabItem`, that are bigger than the content border size.

The second problem can also be solved with negative margins... as far as I know, you won't get the default Scrollviewer to allow any content overflow, no matter how bad you want it. See [WPF clipping even when no clipping is desired - how to turn it off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856225/wpf-clipping-even-when-no-clipping-is-desired-how-to-turn-it-off) for some discussion on the topic.

What you can do is increase the scrollviewers size with a negative margin, so the actual items will stay inside the supported area:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,-3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <TabPanel x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="0,0,0,3"
            IsItemsHost="True" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

This example would allow negative bottom margins on `TabItem` up to 3 px.

Comment: Thank you. Problem 2 was solved in my test program, I still got a very thin line in some zoom states (problem 1) though, but that's the minor problem of the two.

Comment: @Nostromo regarding problem 1, did you increase your negative margin for the selected `TabItem`?

Comment: Yes, the line has a height of 2px. Even when I increase the negative margin to -10px this thin line appears in higher zoom states. And it appears at the same place, so it's not coming from the object with the negative margin.

Comment: @Nostromo try setting a margin for `PART_SelectedContentHost` to see if the thin line moves with the content or stays at the same position. If it's not comming from within the content area, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Putting a margin there changes nothing, but thank you anyway for your help. I think I can live with that thin line for now.